# Is there any difference between these response messages in sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence, diagram, sequence-diagram

Is there any difference between the response messages in the following sequence diagrams?

[image]

[image]

**Moreover**:
Should a sequence diagram be accurate in exposing actors' messages or could it abstract from certain problems which could make the diagram more complex?

More specifically: could a return message be like the one shown here, where it summarises what another piece of the diagram should show instead?

Comment: You ask two questions. Next time, please split it up in two posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rectangles on the life lines show activity of the object. So in the first diagram the object will have some pause between receipt and reply while in the lower one it's straight busy. That might or might not be interesting and depends on the context where you show that diagram.

You can send messages from actor (instances) which is ok to show where the message comes from. It will be obvious that the actor is not really sending the message but it will come from some (unspecific) object being triggered by the actor. However, the way the message is rendered is not ok. Either you let it come of the actor's rectangle below or you let it start completele from mesage endpoint (black bullet).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. 
do you think it's possible to write a message like "mapped as value or group" generalizing a problem which I think instead should be illustrated using some other life lines (as "mapping as value" and "mapping as group")?

Comment: I don't get what you intend here. Better you open another question for that.

Comment: @steame, UML does not prescribe the level of detail you have to include in your diagram. I would advise to do it consistently, i.e. choose which life lines to include in the diagram and then draw all messages exchanged between these lines during the scenario you intend to model by this diagram. You don't have to include all life lines participating in the scenario.